# ASP (.NET 4) ViewState enabled Literal control not retaining changes to HTML contents on PostBack

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listview

I am populating a `ListView` with HTML from a database using a `Literal` with `Text='<%#Eval("HTMLData")'%>`.  When I trigger a PostBack, changes to the loaded HTML are not being reflected in `litRowData.Text`.

`ViewState` is enabled for the page, the `ListView`, and the `Literal` in the `ItemTemplate`, and I am making sure to only populate the `ListView` with initial values from the database when `if(!IsPostBack)` is true in `Page_Load`.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvForm" runat="server"
            DataKeyNames="RowID" ItemPlaceholderID="phRow"
            EnableViewState="true">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phRow" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litRowData" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("HTMLData")%>'
        EnableViewState="true"></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I need to be able to capture changes to the contents of the loaded HTML controls.  Since this HTML comes from a database table, I can't just use ASP controls inside the `ItemTemplate`.  Can anyone see something I'm missing, or suggest an alternative way to do this?

**Edit**:
To clarify a little more, I'm trying to load form input elements dynamically from a database, render them as HTML controls on the page, allow the user to modify their contents by entering text or selecting options, then capture the modified HTML and save it back to the database when the user clicks a save button.

Comment: You say you're only binding data on `!IsPostBack` (i.e. on first page load), and "When I trigger a PostBack, changes to the loaded HTML are not being reflected..."

Why can't you bind `lvForm` regardless of `IsPostBack`?

Comment: Yes, the data is loaded on first Page_Load (!IsPostBack), then the user alters the state of the loaded HTML controls and triggers a PostBack with a save button, but the changed HTML state is not reflected in `litRowData.Text`.

Comment: @maxp: To clarify, if I bound lvForm on every PostBack it would overwrite the HTML with its original state in the database.

Comment: Are you aware Button events (`OnClick` etc) are called after `Page_Load`?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the page life cycle.  This is the reason for using ViewState and only loading the form when `!IsPostBack`.

Comment: What do you mean "When I trigger a PostBack, changes to the loaded HTML are not being reflected in litRowData.Text"? Do you mean that the Literal's Text property is empty? Or is it the same text as if when it was first loaded?

Comment: It is the same text as when it was first loaded.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you're loading HTML control and not ASP control (e.g. input type="text" id="someId") into the literal control. Then, a user will type something and click a button and you want to get the value of the Literal expecting that it should include whatever the user typed? Am I following you?

Comment: That is correct.  If expecting the `Literal` to contain the updated information is a wrong assumption, then I need an alternative to do be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way postback works in .NET is actually a wrapper around the more basic idea of HTML forms. A basic example of HTML forms is:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="type here" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Roughly, what the .NET abstraction adds is:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="string-encoded-value" />
    <input type="text" name="bob" value="type here" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Whereby on postback to your page, all input elements with names are mapped back into properties of your Page object, and the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden field is deserialized into all properties of objects that do not correspond to values of html `input` tags. For example, if `Page.bob` had a `DateTime` property associated with it, it would be stored in `__VIEWSTATE` possibly.

ASP.NET `Literal` tags in Page markup will get printed into the browser exactly as is, meaning that if you have `<span>bob</span>` as its value, that is how it will appear within the `<form>` tag. However, in plain HTML world, `<form>` tags when posted will only contain the values of certain form elements (aka not every `div`, `span`, `p` etc. gets posted back, only `input`, `select`, `textarea` and some others). So if your literal doesn't contain an `input` then it won't even get posted back meaning `__VIEWSTATE` will be used to restore the `Value` property of the `Literal` back to its initial state.

To fix this, you probably don't want to stick html into a `Literal` because even if you do it's not clear that it will get associated with the right property of your page. Instead, try a `TextBox` element or something else that gets written as an `input` element directly by the ASP.NET webforms code. Alternatively, try using javascript to allow modifications of flat text in divs if you don't need to persist the data.

Comment: Well that's good to know (+1), but the HTML I'm interested in capturing actually is the contents of `<input>` tags, so I'm still confused.  Is there a way to associate my `<input>` tags in the database with the correct form used for PostBack?

Comment: The entire page is one form tag, so on postback, odds are that your `Request.Form["input-name-value"]` property contains what you are looking for. But rather than manually extracting that value from the `Form` collection, you should use a `TextBox` instead of `Literal` and it will automatically get tied to a property in your user control

Comment: AKA `<ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="litRowData" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>` and `litRowData.Value = HTMLData`

Comment: Makes sense, I will test and see if this works.  I'd still rather not have everything surrounded by a textbox though.  Is it possible to make it appear as just text (like a `Label`?)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but that just put a bunch of HTML tags inside a TextBox, and TextBox does not appear to have a Value field.

Comment: Sorry, the property is called `.Text` instead of `.Value`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx . Also, if you want it to display without a border you could use CSS or javascript to make it happen. Regardless, if you use the `TextBox` control it should allow it to be updated on postback and maintain its value.

Comment: It does allow postback, but it also does not render its contents as HTML, but instead as a text string of tags.  I need something that acts like Literal but remembers its ViewState like an `<input>` field.

Answer (score 0):

This answer builds on the prior one now that you have a .NET `TextBox` control that is correctly posting back the value of edits. Right below it, you can add to code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litRowData.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "WriteText(this.value)");
}
```

Html:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="litRowData" runat="server"  />
</ItemTemplate>

<div id="yourPreview"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function WriteText(val){
       document.getElementById("yourPreview").innerHTML=val
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That would work except that A) the text in the TextBox is not displayed as HTML and B) some of the input controls added from the database are radio buttons or checkbox lists, where OnKeyUp does not apply.

Comment: The code does not add onKeyUp event to the controls from the database, it adds it to the `TextBox` control that is used to display the text from the database. The purpose of the `onKeyUp` is to take the text from the database (which is in the input element to maintain state with Postback) and copy it into a div element right below it as html. This will cause the "yourPreview" div to show it as it would actually display in HTML.

Comment: OK, but what if I have a radio button rendering in the `yourPreview` div and the user chooses an option.  How is that change sent back to the server in the PostBack?  Also, I'm not sure how OnKeyUp would be triggered from simply loading the HTML from the database into the textbox.  Do you see what I'm getting at? I'm not able to capture state changes to `<input>` tags in the HTML from the database.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware that you needed elements in your dynamic HTML from the database to get mapped back into properties in your page. That's a much tougher proposition, which would require you reveal some more things like are there common property names between these radio buttons and other controls? It's not possible to automatically assign dynamically named input elements into page variables, you'd have to use the `Page.Forms` collection and assign them manually on postback. My answer was for the case where you wanted to record changes to the HTML of the field from the database only.

Comment: OK. Well I don't think checkboxes, textboxes, radio buttons, and textareas have common property names for their values, but I can determine which kind of input control I'm dealing with ahead of time.  Is it possible to dynamically create ASP controls for each type of input control and programatically add them to the ListView to then capture the data?  In other words is it possible to transform the HTML into ASP controls prior to binding the ListView?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but at that point you really shouldn't store them in the DB as HTML but rather as more canonical data like InputType and PropertyName and then translate those into controls on the page (if you have contol over that sort of thing)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  Not much point in using HTML if your going to have to generate everything over again instead.  Unfortunately I don't have much control over how things are stored in the DB.  My current attempt to solve this is to create a custom `Literal` asp server control to store the HTML input tags in ViewState.  Still in progress.